# How do I move data from Landing DB to Staging Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, cron

I am having a gateway that is sending data to MQTT and then to kafka. The data includes mac address of badges, the gateway, time stamp, distance of badge from gateway per interval of time.
I am to only send data to staging db of badge mac address which is closest to the gateway.
What is the best way to filter this data from landing to staging database, as stored procedures on postgresql cannot be scheduled unless we use a cronjob

I have been using stored procedures but it is hindering with the system performance.

Comment: `I have been using stored procedures but it is hindering with the system performance.`, interesting since we use stored procedures to massively improve performance. Could you share the issues you encountered?

Comment: I am running it on a raspberry pi zero, is there any other way other than stored procedure, and also any other way to run it periodically other than cron or pgAgent?